# Iterate randomly over MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, iterator

I have a MongoDB collection of `people`.

For each `person` document, I want to iterate over the rest of the documents in the collection and find a "match" for this person based on certain criteria. The problem is, if I iterate over the documents in the same standard order, the people later in the collection will rarely be assigned a match.

So I would like to randomly iterate over the collection. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Being pragmatic: is the number of persons small enough to store the complete list of IDs in memory and make permutations there?

Comment: One option is to add an `index` field to all documents: 0...n and then each person can use `$rand` to get a random index number to start the iteration from, using a cyclic looping. This will prevent the order of documents from being an issue...

Comment: can you provide what you want to search for and what is the model?

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB v4.4+, you can now use `$rand` to generate a random sort key so you can sort/iterate the collection randomly. You can put it in a `$lookup` sub-pipeline to match some other `person` and use the random sort key to break even.

```js
db.people.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "alice"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "people",
      "let": {
        i: "$interests",
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "randSortKey": {
              "$rand": {}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                // exclude the person himself/herself
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                },
                // find with some shared interest
                {
                  $ne: [
                    [],
                    {
                      "$setIntersection": [
                        "$interests",
                        "$$i"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            randSortKey: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "randomlyMatchedPeople"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RglVLF-nMHn)

---

The above could be a slow solution as it involves generating a random key for every documents in the collection for sorting. One of the workarounds is that you can precompute and materialize the rand key. Then indexing it.

```js
db.collection.updateMany({}, 
[{
    "$addFields": {
        "randSortKey": {
            "$rand": {}
        }
     }
}]);

db.collection.createIndex( { randSortKey: 1 } );
```

The downside of this approach is that it is kind of predetermining the sorting order and make the result not so random. You can periodically regenerate the randSortKey if needed.

Comment: Hi ray. Thank you for your answer. I have questions about performance. Let's says there is 1 million documents coming in the $sort step. This will take a while event if we only want only one document isn't it ?

Comment: @Poyoman sadly, it would be a slow one since it requires doing a collscan and assign the random key to all documents so I only recommend it as a one-off approach. If better performance is required, I would suggest materializing the random key preflight and indexing the random key. However, this may makes the sorting "not so random" since the random key is "seeded" and predetermined. One of the workarounds I experienced is periodically updating and shuffling the random key.

Comment: Depending on how large your result is, you can add the random phase _after_ the filter, less stuff to randomize that way.

Comment: @Zlatko This makes sense. In practice, I think a better approach is we should think about how we define "match". Using some heuristics to define matching score for ranking would be a more consistent way to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Yeah, you can get deep into this, depends on a particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [$sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)

Using @ray's playground,

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "alice"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "people",
      "let": {
        i: "$interests", id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                // exclude the person himself/herself
                {$ne: ["$_id","$$id"]},
                // find with some shared interest
                {
                  $ne: [
                    [], {"$setIntersection": ["$interests","$$i"]}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sample: {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "randomlyMatchedPeople"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z78PxBmhKfr)

Since, it does a random sort, limit of 100 megabytes of RAM for in-memory sorts applies to `$sample` stage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Noel.
I've a question. with $sample i may fall several time on the same interest isn'it ?

Answer (score -1):

Nope, there's no cheap way to iterate randomly over a collection. But, I think using [`parallelCollectionScan`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/parallelCollectionScan/) can help you cover the whole collection more evenly, say by iterating round-robin from the parallel cursors. You could go further and put in some randomness by choosing the next document randomly from the collection of non-exhausted parallel cursors.

Comment: ParallelCollectionScan are deprecated in recent mongodb versions.